# WebSphere Liberty CORS Feature Problems

Tags: cors, websphere-liberty

I am trying to use the new CORS feature in WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.9. I think I have it set up correctly, but it is not working at all, so it's possible that I got the configuration wrong. There is nothing in the log one way or the other - no errors or informational messages.

Is there some kind of trace I could turn on that would show me anything about the CORS feature and possibly why it's not working?

Here is our config:

```
<cors domain="/TalentPlayBookService/rest" allowedOrigins="https://w3dev.somerslab.ibm.com/"
    allowedMethods="GET, HEAD, POST, PUT"
    allowedHeaders="Referer, Cache-Control, Pragma, Accept, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Charset, Content-Type, Content-Length, User-Agent, Authorization, passwd, X-Update-Nonce, X-Shindig-ST, X-IC-CRE-Request-Origin, X-IC-CRE-User, X-LConn-Auth, Accept*, Content*"
    exposeHeaders="Content-Type, Last-Modified, etag" 
    allowCredentials="true" maxAge="3600" />
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The following trace setting will activate CORS logging:

```
<logging traceSpecification="CorsService=finest"/>
```

You should see a "handleRequest" method invocation from CorsRequestInterceptor.

**Edit**:
If you see a trace from "isCorsSupportEnabled" coming back as true, that means your CORS configuration is being picked up.  However, if you do not see a trace entry from "logCorsRequestInfo" it means that the client invocation did not specify the required header called "Origin".

I suggest you do a F12 on your browser to see if the outgoing headers/origin, etc, are as expected.  Specifically, if the "Origin" header is being passed from the client.

**Edit #2** 
Liberty's CORS interceptor is at the filter-level, so think of it as a filter that applies to all domains (apps) that you configure with the cors element in server.xml.  This means that the current CORS support won't handle requests that do not reach the filter layer, such as the 401 you mentioned in your other answer.  This is known limitation that is being taken into consideration for future requirements.

Comment: I turned on the trace, but unfortunately it didn't give me any details that tell me why it's not doing anything with the request. In a nutshell, it's saying this:  
  
handleRequest Entry  

isCorsSupportEnabled Entry  

isCorsSupportEnabled Exit  
  
true  
  
CORS is supported. Handling the request.  
  
handleCorsRequest Entry  
  
Request is fully handled and processed? false  
  
handleCorsRequest Exit  
  
false  
  
handleRequest Exit  
  
false

Comment: Sorry, I can never get my comments to format correctly, even though all the entries have two spaces at the end, are are separated by a line that has two spaces.

Comment: Not being a CORS or HTTP header expert, I'm not sure what to expect to see. I can show you what I'm seeing (broken up because of the limitation on comments):

GET https://tpbp-dev.w3ibm.mybluemix.net/TalentPlayBookService/rest/tpservicedata  
  
And receive the following:  
  
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://tpbp-dev.w3ibm.mybluemix.net/TalentPlayBookService/rest/tpservicedata. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://w3dev.somerslab.ibm.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: Do you have a trace entry from the method "logCorsRequestInfo"?

Comment: No, I'm not seeing any entries for 'logCorsRequestInfo'.  
  
Is there some header that needs to be coming in on the request to WLP that needs to be there?

Comment: After changing the allowedOrigins to an '*', we are now seeing more trace entries. However, we're still getting the same error.    
    <br/>
Since I can't get this to format my comment and it just bunches everything together, I hesitate to paste entries from the trace, because it will be impossible to read. Plus, I'm so limited by the small number of chars I can enter. But here's the final entry.    
<br/>
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.cors.CorsHelper                    handleCorsRequest Exit                                                                                                       false

Comment: I added more info into the answer.  If logCorsRequestInfo is not showing up, that means the "Origin" header was not specified.   Are you now seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I see what the problem is. On a previous project, on an older version of WLP, we needed to create a CORS filter for the application. However, we were using BasicAuth, and were running into a problem when a 401 was returned, because the response did not have the proper CORS headers. Since our CORS filter was specified at the app level, and WLP itself was sending back the 401, our filter never got fired. So we ended up needing to have an AjaxProxy service in between.

With WLP 8.5.5.9, and the CORS feature, I made the bad assumption that, since the feature is configured at the server level, and not in the app, that it would be able to handle a situation like this, where WLP responds with the 401 if the user is not yet authorized. It appears that is not the case here. It seems that this feature does not handle 401s that don't come from the app itself.

So I guess I overestimated the functionality of the CORS feature.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more specific. You're right that security checks at the container level will not have CORS headers added.